# Money plant (Crassula Ovata) growing roots on its branches

Tags: houseplants, indoors, roots, repotting

Early this year the 8+ year old money plant was getting a bit sad and branches kept falling off. I repotted into a larger pot with fresh compost around the existing roots. I also turned it around so that it was facing the other way on the windowsill.

Since repotting it has seemed much happier with new leaves sprouting everywhere and no branches falling off. But there are also what look like roots growing out of the branches. Am I doing anything wrong? I'd guess it was because I turned the plant around. Should I cut these branches off and repot them?

Lots of new branches and leaves...

[image: Lots of new branches]

Roots growing out of the branches?

[image: Roots growing on the branches]

Any advice much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this is the way the plant is telling you it wants to be "sheared" pun intended 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original comment, which seems to have been deleted, explained that the plant is also known as a Jade plant. The link talked about why Jade plants might have aerial roots, as they are known. What I took from the article was that the plant is probably either unhappy or has experienced trauma.

In my case, the plant had been unhappy previously because its branches were starting to drop off with increasing frequency. I repotted it, I believe this was a good thing because the branches stopped falling off. However, at the same time, I also turned it around. My guess is that turning the plant around on the windowsill confused it (or gave it trauma).

My analysis of my situation... Some plants are ok to turn around, but I think something like this plant with woody branches like a tree is not able to grow towards the light very quickly. Hence, instead of growing towards the light, it had to make new branches pointing towards the outdoors, and it made some roots on the dark side. It knows where the light is. It knows the light isn't where it was. It knows where it is dark, so it puts roots on the dark side. I imagine in the wild this would be its response if it had fallen over.

The link talked about what to do with the roots. He was saying that you **could** remove them from the main plant and grow them separately. However, he also said that if the plant is still in the process of making more and more roots, maybe this might be a bad idea, and wait until the roots have calmed down. He also said that cutting off the roots carefully should be ok too.

Comment: Here is the linked article: https://gardenforindoor.com/jade-plant-growing-aerial-roots/.